# Zip and UnZip folder

Tags: swift

i made an app in Swift but I need to download .zip files on my website, and use the content (images) in app. Actually, I download the .zip file and store it in documents, and I need to unzip the file into the same documents folder.

Comment: Always share possible code to get better ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Install [ZipFoundation](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation) pods to your app**

**2. `import ZipFoundation`**

**Unzipping Archives**

To unzip existing archives, you can use FileManager.unzipItem(at sourceURL: URL, to destinationURL: URL).
This recursively extracts all entries within the archive to the destination URL:

```
let fileManager = FileManager()
let currentWorkingPath = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
var sourceURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: currentWorkingPath)
sourceURL.appendPathComponent("archive.zip")
var destinationURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: currentWorkingPath)
destinationURL.appendPathComponent("directory")
do {
    try fileManager.createDirectory(at: destinationURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    try fileManager.unzipItem(at: sourceURL, to: destinationURL)
} catch {
    print("Extraction of ZIP archive failed with error:\(error)")
}
```